# Sufficiency for existence of $lim_{\mathcal{B}}f(x)$, Zorich

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, filters

I am working on Mathematical analysis 1 by Zorich and i am stuck at the proof for the sufficiency of the cauchy criterion for the existence of a limit of a function (page 132)

[image]

I am understanding all of the sufficiency proof except for the last concluding sentence.. Here is the context:

[image]

Here is my interpretation, of which i am doubting:

> We conclude that $\lim_\mathcal{B}f(x) = A\ \ $ because $\forall \epsilon>0$, by taking $B_n \in \mathcal{B}$ with $n> 1/\epsilon$, we have that $\forall x\in B_n:|f(x)-A|\leq1/n<\epsilon$

I base my reasoning on the fact that what Zorich deduces one sentence earlier : $|f(x_n)-A|\leq1/n$, should hold $\forall x \in B_n$

**I am however unsure of this fact and would appreciate clarification.**

I am also thrown off by his mentionning of $\omega(f,B_n)$ in the last sentence, and his use of $2/\epsilon$ rather than $1/\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n\gt [2/\epsilon]+1$ implies $n\gt 2/\epsilon$ (which is the same as $1/n\lt\epsilon/2$), because for every number $x$ the relation $[x]\le x\lt [x]+1$ holds.

Now fix such an $n$ and also $B_n$. If $x\in B_n$, since $x_n\in B_n$ as well, we will have $|f(x)-f(x_n)|\lt 1/n$ due to the assumption $\omega(f;B_n)\lt 1/n$.

Therefore, for any $x\in B_n$, we will have $|f(x)-A|\le |f(x)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-A|\lt 1/n+1/n=2/n\lt\epsilon$, which is the definition of limit.

Comment: very clear explanation! thanks for the missing step